Android ndk missing gold linker on MacOS
I have downloaded the gold linker for mac from android's site but I've found out that it is missing the gold linker. How can I get it?
If I compile my SDL project using CMake for Android, clang will give this error:
C/C++: Debug enabled
C/C++: Building for Android
C/C++: : && /Users/<me>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi19 --sysroot=/Users/<me>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -flto=thin -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--gc-sections    -fuse-ld=gold CMakeFiles/boo.dir/main.cpp.o -o boo  libfoo.a  -latomic -lm && :
C/C++: clang++: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=gold'
C/C++: clang++: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=gold'
C/C++: ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
C/C++: CMake Warning:
C/C++:   Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
C/C++:     ANDROID_APP_PLATFORM
C/C++:     ANDROID_LD

Is there some way to stop gradle from using gold linker?

You're using NDK r25. Gold and BFD were both removed in r23 (they're part of binutils). r22 and r21 announced the upcoming removal.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/BuildSystemMaintainers.md#Linkers is the "what tools do I use?" doc.
Remove those flags from your build to fix the build failure.
